# JDBC connection working on co-worker's computer not mine

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, windows-firewall

The following java code prints Hello World on my co-worker's computer:

```
public void testJDBC() throws Exception
{
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://myremoteserver.mycorp.net:1433;DatabaseName=mydb";
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "myuser", "mypwd");
    System.out.println("Hello world");
}
```

On debugging, the `getConnection` step does not return. I can connect to myserver.mycorp.net,1433 using SQL Server Management Studio.

I even changed `myremoteserver.mycorp.net` to `127.0.0.1,5802` (local database). And again with `127.0.0.1,5802` under *Server Name* in the *Connect to Database* step in SQL Server Management studio I can connect to the database, but the `getConnection` step does not return. No error message/exception either.

Specs: Eclipse Indigo, SQL Server 2008, Windows 7 Enterprise

Comment: How many concurrent connections does your database allow?

Comment: Do you mean the getConnection call returns null?

Comment: It was a java compiler issue, thanks for the help (please see my answer)

Comment: Which JDBC driver were you using - the new JDBC 4.0 one from MSFT? (which came out in March 2012)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by upgrading the Java version for the eclipse project from JDK 6 to JDK 7.